# GA4 conversion tracking running in debug but not live onsite

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, conversion-tracking

We have setup ecommerce conversion tracking through tag manager which seems to work in debugView and preview mode but still won't record live conversions on the site.

The tags have been published and its set up exactly the same as on other sites we have worked on which work fine. Any one know what could be causing this?

(Was wondering if it could have anything to do with UA conversion tracking still running?)

We tested it out in debug which works, published the changes on GTM, waited the 24-48 hours checked the setup against another site which is running conversions perfectly fine.

Comment: Any updates? What was it in the end?

Comment: We couldn't get it to work directly though tag manager so had to get the GTM4WP plugin which seemed to do the trick.